# During Caesarean section: What is the name of the instrument in which the scar is burned to close it?

Tags: scar-tissue-scars, c-section, instruments

This is my first question in this community and I'm not sure if this question belongs here, but I hope you can help me anyway, because it's very important.

An acquaintance of mine had had a caesarean section. Her c-section was lasered with some kind of pincer. I am not sure if it is a pincer, but I know that doctors need this instrument to close the Caesarean section.

Now I'm looking for the name of this device. 
Do you know what this instrument is called? This instrument seems to be getting very hot!

I hope you can help me as soon as possible.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing a form of cauterizing tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the description, the instrument you are looking for should be a bipolar coagulation forceps.

[image]
[ref: medicalexpo](http://img.medicalexpo.com/images_me/photo-m/70641-8603370.jpg)

It is used to stop bleeding by coagulation of smaller vessels, bigger one will still have to be closed by e.g. a [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(medicine)).
It's part of the instruments used in the [Electrosurgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrosurgery), which uses high-frequency alternating polarity,  typically in the radio frequency (RF) range of 100 kHz to 5 MHz, to minimize the effects of muscle and neural stimulation.
An other application area for bipolar would be the destruction of maligne tissues, e.g. tumors.
With the bipolare the current in the patient is restricted to the tissue touched by the forceps electrode which helps to prevent damage to other sensitive tissues as it would be possible with the often used monopolare.
The monopolar instrument another member of electrosurgery would be , more looking like a wired pen or scalpell where a big dispersive electrode is placed elsewhere on the patients body to close the circuit, is mainly used for fulguration and cutting with simultaneous coagulation.